# Is there a way to Merge two stack overflow user accounts

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

So my Google accounts primary email address has changed.  This means now when I log into SO, I don't have access to my old posts as a new account seem to have been created :-(

Is there anyway to merge my old SO account into my new account?

Comment: wow didnt know that existed will move.

Comment: Already happened.

Comment: What happened? The merger, the migration, or the Great Croissant Debate?

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link https://stackoverflow.com/contact, fill the form,

- In first dropdown selection option "I need to merge user profiles"
- Your current email
- Your current profile's link
- Your Other profile's link
- Describe your problem, how you get into this problem or what happened to your old profile ?

SE developer will help you out by merging your profile with old one, once validations are done.

Comment: what what happens to the rep? does that get summed up too?